# Gunicorn is failing with OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I was facing this issue while running my application [`Docker Image`] with the gunicorn version 19.9.0 in `Openshift`. I'm not using the nginx to set [secure_scheme_headers]:https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1766.

## Gunicorn Configuration

`gunicorn --chdir /src/app wsgi:application  --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 4 --timeout 180 -k gevent`

## error

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 66, in handle
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/six.py", line 625, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 49, in handle
    req = six.next(parser)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/http/parser.py", line 41, in __next__
    self.mesg = self.mesg_class(self.cfg, self.unreader, self.req_count)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/http/message.py", line 181, in __init__
    super(Request, self).__init__(cfg, unreader)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/http/message.py", line 54, in __init__
    unused = self.parse(self.unreader)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/http/message.py", line 230, in parse
    self.headers = self.parse_headers(data[:idx])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/http/message.py", line 74, in parse_headers
    remote_addr = self.unreader.sock.getpeername()
OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected```

# Fix
I was able to fix the issue by shifting the older version of gunicorn==19.7.1
and gevent didn't work with the older version of the gunicorn.
https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1913
````

Comment: Not nearly enough information here. What gunicorn configuration are you using?

Comment: Running with single command not much configurations

Comment: looks like this issue [#1913](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1913). Not fixed yet.

Comment: This error occurs when you run the gunicorn command you're showing above? Or what are you doing to get this error?

Comment: @NalinDobhal issue is coming. Please check this link: https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1913

Comment: @dirkgroten Issue coming when I ran application in Opeshift  with Docker Image. Gunicorn running command is above as the entrypoint.

Comment: Gunicorn is working with gunicorn==19.7.1 without any issues. The root cause gunicorn version, after going to old version issue is resolved.

Comment: Any solution for this error? i got the same error.. python 3.8 flask + gunicorn

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, this is the same issue as [#1993](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1913) and it is fixed in the pull request [#2277](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/pull/2277). It is merged and available in the latest version of Gunicorn, version [20.1.0](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/releases/tag/20.1.0)

So by updating to this version of Gunicorn, the problem is solved for me.